# Creating variable in SQL and using in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I want to create a variable that counts the number of times each customer ID appears in the CSV, and then I want the output to be all customer IDs that appear 0,1,or 2 times. Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT Customers.customer_id , COUNT(*) AS counting
FROM Customers 
LEFT JOIN Shopping_cart ON Customers.customer_id = Shopping_cart.customer_id
WHERE counting = '0' 
   OR counting = '1' 
   OR counting = '2' 
GROUP BY Customers.customer_id;
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the database you are using ,e.g. SQL Server 2016, MySQL.

Comment: I am not understand the question so far. You want all customer ids that between 0 and 2 occurrences?

Comment: when a answer helps you please mark it as answer....

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Customers.customer_id , COUNT(*) AS counting
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Shopping_cart on Customers.customer_id=Shopping_cart.customer_id
WHERE COUNT(*) < 3
GROUP BY Customers.customer_id;
```

The query groups all customer ids, and with count(*) we get the number of items in a group. So for your solution you call the group count(*) and say only the items where the group count is smaller then 3. Smaller then 3 includes (0,1,2). You can reuse the count() in the query.

Comment: Perhaps you can improve your answer by adding an explanation for why this works.

Comment: You must not use an aggregate in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.

For example:

```
select JOB, COUNT(JOB) from SCOTT.EMP
group by JOB
HAVING count(JOB) > 1 ;
```

While a tad odd, you may be specific about the HAVING condition(s):

```
HAVING count(JOB) = 2 or count(JOB) = 4
```

Note: the WHERE clause is used for filtering rows and it applies on each and every row, while the HAVING clause is used to filter groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a filter *after* the aggregation with the HAVING clause.
Please note that `count(*)` counts all rows, including empty ones, so you cannot use it to detect customers without any shopping cart; you have to count the non-NULL values in some column instead:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       count(Shopping_cart.some_id) AS counting
FROM Customers 
LEFT JOIN Shopping_cart USING (customer_id)
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING count(Shopping_cart.some_id) BETWEEN 0 and 2;
```